# Volume between paraboloid and cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

> Find the volume blocked between $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and $z=x^2+y^2$.

So one way is to use cylindrical coordinates, which actually worked for me, but I'm wondering why this solution doesn't work:

Our shapes intersect at $(0,0,0)$ and the plane $z=1$.

So we want to find the volume of: $\Omega = \left \{ (x,y,z) : z^2 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq z, 0 \leq z \leq 1\right \}$.

Using Fubini's Theorem: $$V = \int_{\Omega}1dV = \int_0^1 \int_{z^2 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq z} 1 dV^2dz$$

Now we can notice the inner integral is the area between 2 circles, so we have:

$$\int_0^1 \int_{z^2 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq z} 1 dV^2dz = \int_0^1 \pi z^2-\pi z^4dz= \frac{2 \pi}{15}$$

But the answer should be $$\frac{2 \pi}{12}$$

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle V = \int_0^1 (\pi z^2-\pi z^4dz) \ $ step has a mistake.

Please note that the area is $(\pi z - \pi z^2)$ and not $(\pi z^2-\pi z^4)$.

So the integral should be $V = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \pi (z - z^2) \ dz = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Comment: oh right, $x^2+y^2$ is the radius after already being squared, thanks, missed it.